# Conditinal database record delete firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to clean some records of a firestore database. I have a function that receives the records I would like to keep, I check in all the records if id is not in the `docsToKeep:firebase` documents argument.
I use a `foreach` for all the records, and I user filter to find the matching id as shown in the working snippet below:

```
async function checkForNotifClean(docsToKeep:firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot<firebase.firestore.DocumentData>) {
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const notifCollection = db.collection('notifications')
  const allData = await notifCollection.get();
  allData.docs.forEach(doc => {
    const filtered = docsToKeep.docs.filter(entry => entry.id === doc.id); 
    const needsErase = filtered.length === 0;
    if (needsErase) {
      const id = doc.id; 
      notifCollection.doc(id).delete();
    }
  })
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to erase all the documents that are not in `docsToKeep` ? Would be kind of function that get all the objects that are not in both arrays and delete those. I would be happy on improvements on the javascript side to filter out the records to delete, and in the firebase side, improvements regarding the chance of deleting some set of records at once instead of looping through all and deleting each.

Answer (score 1):

To delete (or write to) a document in Firestore you need to know the complete path to that document, including its document ID. If you don't have the IDs of the documents to delete, then your only option is to determine those IDs as you're doing now.

It does lead to the question how `docsToKeep` is populated though. My guess it that the user already selects some documents from a full list. If that's the case, might you be able to pass the inverted list: `docsToDelete`?

Comment: thanks for your answer. The thing is that I use only some records for the notifications in the app, lets say de last 6 notifications. So I handle the 6 more recent notifs and the rest can be erased. From that departing point I was asking if there is a more direct way to obtain the set of records to delete from the two sets of records (set1: all the records and set2: the records to keep) and on the firebase side to delete those at once.

Comment: According to your answer it seems that in the firebase side to delete a set of records yo need to loop through all the ids and delete those in a loop, correct?

Comment: Yes. To delete a document in Firestore you need to know the complete path to that document, including its document ID. If you don't have the IDs of the documents to delete, then your only option is to determine those IDs as you're doing now.

Comment: Based on what you are doing you could tweak your query to be "get all documents older than <time of oldest docToKeep>", then delete any hits on that query. You could also atomically delete them using a [Batched Write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes).